# Is there a nice browser to view a data-dump?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, closed-sites, xml

Flipping through text files of XML to try to read what was going on at [a dead site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15025/how-things-work) makes it difficult to get the gist of it.  Is there some tool that will order the posts into Q and A's and sprinkle in the comments?

Comment: it would be nice to be able to see at least the top Qs of a dead site.

Comment: Hmm, I may consider writing one.

Answer (score 3):

A simple excel Pivot table, cross linking the Parent IDs of Post Types 2(Answers) with the post IDs of the Questions, gives a nice view with Question and nested answer Texts.

I already have workable copies of a few, that I may share if solicited.